# Java, wait and notifyAll: guard against spurious wakeups

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have several threads that does some work, and then must go to sleep/wait for an undetermined time. Later they all need to be waken up and resume their work. I can do this by calling `wait()` on an object and then `notifyall()` on the same object when they need to resume. When researching this issue i discovered this tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html
Apparantly it is good practice to guard against missed signals and spurious wakeups by storing the signal inside the signal class and check the signal member variable inside a while loop.
Here is the code example from the tutorial:

```
public class MonitorObject{
}

public class MyWaitNotify3{

  MonitorObject myMonitorObject = new MonitorObject();
  boolean wasSignalled = false;

  public void doWait(){
    synchronized(myMonitorObject){
      while(!wasSignalled){
        try{
          myMonitorObject.wait();
         } catch(InterruptedException e){...}
      }
      //clear signal and continue running.
      wasSignalled = false;
    }
  }

  public void doNotify(){
    synchronized(myMonitorObject){
      wasSignalled = true;
      myMonitorObject.notify();
    }
  }
}
```

This code is working, but I need to wake up all threads and not just one. If I replace `myMonitorObject.notify();` with `myMonitorObject.notifyAll();` that will not work because the first thread that resumes work will set the `wasSignalled` flag to `false` and all the other threads will be trapped in the while loop.

I have made some changes that will enable me to wake up all threads:

```
MonitorObject myMonitorObject = new MonitorObject();
boolean wasSignalled = false;

public void doWait(){
    synchronized(myMonitorObject){
        while(!wasSignalled){
            try{
                myMonitorObject.wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
        }

    }
}

public void resetSignal() {
    wasSignalled = false;
}

public void doNotifyAll() {
    synchronized(myMonitorObject){
        wasSignalled = true;
        myMonitorObject.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

But this is not a very good solution, because now I can't wake up just one thread, and I have to reset the signal after `doNotify` before I can use doWait again.

Does anyone have a solution that will enable me to use both `notify` or `notifyAll` on the threads that is waiting?

And one thing about the example I do not understand, why do I have to use a separate MonitorObject class at all? Why can't I just call `wait` and `notify` on the `MyWaitNotify` class itself?

Like this:

```
public class WaitNotify {
    boolean wasSignalled = false;

    public void doWait(){
        synchronized(this){
            while(!wasSignalled){
                try{
                    wait();
                } catch(InterruptedException e){

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void resetSignal() {
        wasSignalled = false;
    }

    public void doNotifyAll() {
        synchronized(this){
            wasSignalled = true;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to be working, any reason I should not be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html#awaitAdvance%28int%29) is a good high-level tool for this kind of use case.

```
    final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);

    doNotify()
        phaser.arrive();  // increase phase

    doWait()
        int phase = phaser.getPhase();
        phaser.awaitAdvance( phase );   // await phase change
```

`synchronized` on a privately owned object has the advantage that nobody else could do `synchronized` on it. If you do `synchronized(this)`, there is a chance that someone else may also want to use `this` as a lock object.

Comment: Thanks, actually a CountDownLatch was sufficient for my purposes, but I wouldn't have found it without your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a generation integer. When a thread blocks, block until the generation integer changes. Before calling `notifyAll`, increment the generation integer.

Comment: yes. the `boolean` version is a generation integer too in disguise. or we can just simply flip a boolean.

Comment: @bayou.io Then what happens if it gets flipped twice before a thread wakes up? The thread will go back to sleep.

Comment: true:) but what if the integer is increased 2^32 times? :) just kidding.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate a bit, a small code sample?

Comment: @BruceB It would help if you were more specific about what you didn't understand.

Comment: Actually I saw the answer from bayou.io and found that a CountDownLatch was sufficient for my purposes, I guess it's better to use a library function when possible, thanks anyway.